# Why does find:s -or fail when I add a -print0 at the end?

Tags: find

I am writing a little script the modifies some movies in a directory tree, 
and I would like to parse that tree with a bash for loop or similar.

So I started to find the files with

```
find -iname *.mov -or -iname *.mkv -or -iname *.avi
```

and he shows me some files of each kind just as expected.

But then I try to loop over the result with this (since there is whitespace in some of the dir names).

```
find -iname *.mov -or -iname *.mkv -or -iname *.avi -print0 | while read -d $'\0' line
do
    echo $line
done
```

But now he only returns the avi files!
So it seems like when I add the -print0 he ignores my -or and the other -iname.

What is going on here, what am I missing?

Do I need to send the result from find into a tmpfile before looping over the result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-print0` action only attaches itself to the last test (`-iname *.avi` in this case). Either repeat the print action for each match, or do some grouping.

```
find -iname '*.mov' -print0 -or -iname '*.mkv' -print0 -or -iname '*.avi' -print0
```

or

```
find \( -iname '*.mov' -or -iname '*.mkv' -or -iname '*.avi' \) -print0
```

And careful with those `*` - from the `find` man page:

> Please note that you should quote patterns as a matter of course,
>   otherwise the shell will expand any wildcard characters in them.

A slightly more concise form if your `find` has that option:

```
find -iregex '.*\.\(mov\|mkv\|avi\)$' -print0
```

(And you might want to add `-type f` in case you ever find yourself naming directories with those extensions.)

Comment: Good point with the type f to void dirs with bad names.